# How to route symfony2 404 to symfony1 legacy app

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, symfony1, integration

I'm migrating a symfony1.4 application to symfony 2.5, and we need to run both applications simultaneously seamlessly to the end user.

The idea is to land on sf2 app and if a certain route does not exist, then route (fall back) to the sf1 app.

The challenge here is to use the same domain.

For instance:

- www.mydomain.com/ > lands on sf2 home page.
- www.mydomain.com/contact-us > routes to an existing sf2 controller/view
- www.mydomain.com/some-form > does not exists in sf2 app, then it redirects/forwards to the legacy sf1.4 app keeping the same url (user doesn't need to notice the forwarding)

Any ideas on how to best approach this?

Cheers, 
Fabian

Comment: Can you make a physical directory "some-form" and run a second instance of symfony in it? You would need to play with htaccess so that the symfony2 controller doesn't think it's part of that project and the symfony1.4 instance works in that directory. We've done this a few times running a wordpress installation in a symfony project.

Answer (score 2):

I think this wrapper bundle was designed for your purpose:

https://github.com/theodo/TheodoEvolutionLegacyWrapperBundle

> This bundle allows you to call the legacy framework from Symfony2. Tested and works for legacy app made with symfony 1.4.